# Difference between 1D and ND plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been plotting on Matplotlib for sometime and have noticed that some plotting techniques like 3D plotting and others require data to be present in arrays having dimensions of more than 1D. For instance, If I have 1D arrays X,Y,Z, then I won't be able to plot them in the 3D plots. However, if I reshape the same arrays to 2D or any ND and then I am able to plot them in 3D. My question is, why do you think this happens? More importantly, is there a difference between a reshaped and 1D array (in terms of its data)?

Answer (score 1):

Let's investigate `ax.contour`. There is an [example in the docs](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo.py):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
print(X.shape, Y.shape, Z.shape)
# ((120, 120), (120, 120), (120, 120))
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The print statement shows that `ax.contour` can accept 2D inputs. 
If we were to change the `X` and `Y` arrays to 1D arrays:

```
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
X = X.reshape(-1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1)
print(X.shape, Y.shape, Z.shape)
```

Then we get

```
((14400,), (14400,), (120, 120))
```

as the shapes, and a `TypeError` is raised:

```
TypeError: Length of x must be number of columns in z,
and length of y must be number of rows.
```

So it appears there is no choice. `ax.contour` expects 2D arrays.

Comment: I understand your point..but consider me having three 1D arrays through which I want to generate 3D contour plots..in which case, I am not able to do so. Matplotlib asks me to give 2D arrays (at least on the z axis). My point is..what is the difference between [1,2,3,4,5,6] and [[1,2,3][4,5,6]] in terms of data analysis? Will both of them give the exact plots?